# How can i make two random numbers keep a certain distance away from each other?

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I'm new to javascript programming but i am aware of how messy my code is, so i'm sorry for that. What Im trying to do is create 2 (for now, final version will have many) "Trees" that are just rectangles for now place on a random x value. But I don't want them to be within 40 pixels of eachother. I've been trying to write something that should achieve this but I can't figure out why it wont work, trees are still spawning on top of eachother! It's driving me crazy. I am using p5js and sublime text 2 by the way.

```
function bg(){
    var tree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (380 - 0) + 00);
    var tree2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (380 - 0) + 0);
    redefine(tree,tree2);
    this.x=0;

    this.show = function(){
        noStroke();

        //tree
        fill(102, 51, 0);
        rect(this.x+tree , 450, 26, 110);

        //tree2
        fill(102, 51, 0);
        rect(this.x+tree2, 410, 26, 150);   
    }
}

function redefine(first, second){
    if(second<=first-40 || second>=first+40){
        console.log("good");
    } else {
        console.log("redefining")
        second = Math.floor(Math.random() * (380 - 0) + 0);
    }
}

//key
// Math.random() * (max - min) + min
```

Comment: can u create a snippet ?

Comment: @DeepakSharma im sorry whats a snippet?

Comment: like jsfiddle in stackoverflow. so we can run test code here

Comment: @DeepakSharma how would I do that with multiple js files?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're only giving your `redefine` function one chance to roll another random number. You could change it to a loop that keeps trying until they're the right distance apart.

Answer (score 0):

In redefine, you try and change the value of "second," but that does not modify "tree2" because it is a locally scoped primitive variable.  Assuming your other logic is sound, something like this may work:

```
function bg(){


var tree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (380 - 0) + 00);
var tree2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (380 - 0) + 0);

while(isOverlapping(tree, tree2)) {
    tree2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (380 - 0) + 0);
}

this.x=0;

this.show = function(){
noStroke();

//tree
fill(102, 51, 0);
rect(this.x+tree , 450, 26, 110);

//tree2
fill(102, 51, 0);
rect(this.x+tree2, 410, 26, 150);   
    }
}

function isOverlapping(first, second){
    if(second<=first-40 || second>=first+40){
        console.log("good");
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("redefining")
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the "define" approach instead of "redefine":

```
function bg() { 

    var tries   =   define(tree, tree2);
    var tree    =   tries[0];
    var tree2   =   tries[1];   


    this.x = 0;

    this.show = function () {
    noStroke();

    //tree
    fill(102, 51, 0);
    rect(this.x + tree, 450, 26, 110);

    //tree2
    fill(102, 51, 0);
    rect(this.x + tree2, 410, 26, 150);
    }

}

function define() {

    var tries       =   [];
        tries[0]    =   0;
        tries[1]    =   0;
    var i           =   0;

    while(tries[1] - tries[0] <=  40 && tries[0] - tries[1] <=  40){

        tries[0]    = Math.floor(Math.random() * (380 - 0) + 0);
        tries[1]    = Math.floor(Math.random() * (380 - 0) + 0);        
        i++;
        console.info('iter:',i,' inside tree:',tries[0],' tree2:',tries[1]);

    }

    return tries;
}
```